# making my jquery code work good with ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

this is my code for now:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("div#main").hide();
$("div#footer").hide();
setTimeout(function () { $("div#main").fadeIn("slow"); }, 2000);
setTimeout(function () { $("div#footer").fadeIn("slow"); }, 2000);
});
```

and this is the site:
http://thecodefixer.com/tatmuda/blog/

please view in ie8 and see what happens

i need to see the background image first and then that the main content square and the footer will show up fading in....(just like in firefox and chrome...works great)

someone know how to fix this in ie8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default those two elements to `display:none` in CSS.  It looks like the problem in IE8 is that everything is taking too long to load and your #main and #footer are `block` at the start.  Then when jQuery is finally 'ready', those elements are hidden.  This is what makes them flicker like that.  So add this to your page to see if that's the case:

```
#main{display:none;}
#footer{display:none;}
```